# i use specific data base helper and get error message " Call to a member function whereRaw() on array"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

good day;
 I create data base helper to reduce my code in laravel frame work ,
but when I use function in my helper  I recice error message "Call to a member function whereRaw() on array",
this is my helper code

```
namespace App\Helpers;
    use DB;

    class dBHelper
    {
        /**
         * This functin retrive all data with pagination .
         */

        public static function pagination($dbName,$Tablename,$Condition="",$data)
        {
            $stattment =DB::connection(''.$dbName.'')-> select('select * from  '.$Tablename.' ')
                ->whereRaw(''.$Condition.'', $data)
                ->Paginate(1);

            return $stattment;
        }


    }
```

this is my controller

```
$dataView['products']=dBHelper::pagination('mysql','products','`status`=? AND `deleted`=?',array(1,1));
```

Comment: You're trying to call `whereRaw()` on an array. Presumably this is what `select()` returns.

Comment: I want to give condition passing it into array to filter  data like where status=1 and deleted =1  I do this function to use pagination  you can help me if I passing filter using array to use pagination I can wrjite this statement " $stattment =DB::connection(''.$dbName.'')-> select('select * from '.$Tablename.' WHERE '.$Condition.' ',$data);" and it work but icant use pagination you can help me  if  tell me how to paginate data using this statemt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `select()` method actually runs the query.

Your `DB::connection('name')` call returns an instance of

```
Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface
```

This has a select method

```php
/**
 * Run a select statement against the database.
 *
 * @param  string  $query
 * @param  array   $bindings
 * @param  bool  $useReadPdo
 * @return array
 */
public function select($query, $bindings = [], $useReadPdo = true);
```

As you can see the return type here is `array`.

Your best bet is to call the `table()` method, which will return a fluent query builder.

```php
/**
 * Begin a fluent query against a database table.
 *
 * @param  string  $table
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
public function table($table);
```

So, to achieve what you want, your code should be as follows.

```php
return DB::connection($dbName)
    ->table($tableName)
    ->select(['*'])
    ->whereRaw($condition, $data)
    ->paginate($count);
```

This will return an instance of

```
\Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
```

I should add that `paginate(1)` will return a paginated list of 1 record. If you only want one, use `first()` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear it @AhmedGaber. You can click the tick under the arrows next to my answer to mark it as correct. That way the question will show as answered and others who find this in the future will be shown the solution.